How can I tell if functions from a module can be run in parallel?
Suppose that I want to run the following dbatools-using foreach in parallel. How can I tell if the dbatools functions are safe to run in parallel?
$options = New-DbaScriptionOption
$options.ScriptForCreateOrAlter = $true
$options.SchemaQualify = $true
$options.IncludeDatabaseContext = $true
$options.EnforceScriptingOptions = $true

foreach($instance in $instances) {
    $location = "D:\foo\$($instance)\"
    Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $instance |
    Sort-Object Name |
    % {Find-DbaStoredProcedure -SqlInstance $instance -Database $_.Name -Pattern '.'
    } |
    % {Get-DbaStoredProcedure -SqlInstance $instance -Database $_.Database -Name $_.Name
    } |
    % {
        $SaveLocation = "$($location)\$($_.Database)\$($_.Schema)\";
        Export-DbaScript -InputObject $_ -NoPrefix -ScriptingOptionsObject $options -FilePath "$($Path)\$($_.Name).sql" -Path $Path
    }
}


You can make + test your changes and then observe whether the outcome changes :)

@MathiasR.Jessen Race conditions are notoriously hard to debug. Merely testing might not be good enough.

Will your parallel function work on the same sets of data ?  If you can guarantee that it will work on subsets of data you can safely run it in parallel - that's a basic divide and conquer scheme.
On the other hand if the data overlaps (or any of the underlying control structures and mechanisms) you may risk race conditions.

My guess is that if you limit the parallelism to each thread communicating with a distinct instance, with instance names (strings) serving as input, you'll be fine, along the lines of $instances | ForEach-Object -Parallel { ... }
